# How to apply different conditions to each column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

Suppose I have a dataframe with three columns.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(2,4,6,8)
c <- c(3,6,9,12)
df <- cbind(a,b,c)
df
```

This gives you...

```
     a b  c
[1,] 1 2  3
[2,] 2 4  6
[3,] 3 6  9
[4,] 4 8 12
```

Now suppose I want to create a new dataframe that takes the value TRUE if the value is greater than the column mean and FALSE if it's less than the column mean.

If I use the following command it uses the mean for the whole dataframe.

```
large <- df > mean(df)
large
```

So I get...

```
         a     b     c
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I would like to get

```
         a     b     c
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mean` gets a single value for the whole `matrix`, we need `colMeans`

```
df > colMeans(df)[col(df)]
```

Or transpose the dataset, do the comparison and transpose

```
t(t(df) > colMeans(df))
```

Comment: Thanks. Now what if it was a different statistic, like the standard deviation?

Comment: @PashaS. You can use `df > apply(df, 2, sd)[col(df)]`. or a vectorized option with `library(matrixStats)`  `df > colSds(df)[col(df)]`

Answer (score 4):

This method will work for both data.frames and matrices (your example `df` is actually a matrix, not a data.frame)

```
sweep(df, 2, colMeans(df), '>')
#          a     b     c
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or, as suggested by @markus (same output and also works for both matrices and data.frames)

```
scale(df, scale = FALSE) > 0
```

If it is actually a data.frame, I believe using `Map` as below is faster than the methods above. However, if it is a matrix then using `Map` will not work at all.

```
as.data.frame(Map('>', df, colMeans(df)))
```

Comment: Don't know if this is any better but you might add this option to your post: `scale(df, scale = FALSE) > 0`